# What does $pr(x)$ function mean?

Tags: continuity, notation

During a proof about the continuity of a function my teacher said that if $V$ is a neighbourhood to $(t,x)$ in $\mathbb{R}\times X$ then $pr_{\mathbb{R}}(V)$ is a neighbourhood to $t$ in $\mathbb{R}$. My question is what is $pr_{\mathbb{R}}(V)$?

Comment: $$pr_{\mathbb{R}}(V)=\{t\in\mathbb R\mid\exists x\in X,\,(t,x)\in V\}$$

Comment: @Did, Thank you this makes a lot of sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The projection of $V$ into $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thank you, Is there something I could read about this like Wikipedia page or something?

Comment: it depends how you define [Projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(mathematics)) - i usually use a [Restriction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restriction_(mathematics)), so that $pr_\mathbb{R}(V)=V|_\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Does $pr_{\mathbb{R}}(V)$ also reduce the number of variables because   $V$ is a neighbourhood to $(t,x)$ (two variables) in $\mathbb{R}\times X$ but $pr_{\mathbb{R}}(V)$ is a neighbourhood to $t$ in $\mathbb{R}$ (one varaible)

Comment: somehow you need to ignore the x component in the projection into R